# Angular does not save the $scope.$watch order

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a code that is responsible for ordering elements in my controller. 
Here is the code:

```
$scope.$watch('applications', function (applications) {
    if (angular.isArray(applications) && applications.length !== 0) {
        var landing_app = _.findWhere(applications, {
            area_name : $scope.landingAreaName
        });
        applications = _.reject(applications, function(app){
            return app.id == landing_app.id;
        });
        applications.unshift(landing_app);
    }
});
```

When I `console.log` the `applications` variable - it has the correct order of the elements. But it is not maintained in the view. What is wrong here?

Update:

when I use this code:

```
$scope.$watch('applications', function (applications) {
    if (angular.isArray(applications) && applications.length !== 0) {
        applications.sort(function (a) {
            return a.area_name !== $scope.landingAreaName;
        });
    }
});
```

it does change the order of applications, but it is not the order that I want.

Comment: You are reassigning the `applications` variable from outer scope, the case is most likely that `$scope.applications` and `applications` are pointing to different object. Can you provide a minimal complete code sample in snippet or jsfiddle?

Comment: Plese add more code that is causing the change in the `$scope.application`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that variables are passed by value, not reference, in JS – so your assignment to `application` is only local:

```
var x = 3;
(function (x) {
  x++; // x = 4
}(x));
// here, back to x = 3
```

So, that's where the "rule of the dot" comes from in angular:

```
var obj = {x: 3};
(function (obj) {
  obj.x++; // obj.x = 4
}(obj));
// obj.x is still 4 here, because obj's **contents** weren't copied.
```

In this case, the simplest solution is to modify `$scope`:

```
$scope.applications = _.reject(...);
```

Note: any destructive operation will work (like `unshift`), because it acts on the content.

Comment: That means, that when I used reject in my code, I have created a new object, which did not have relation to $scope.applications. But when I used sort, I was modifying the scope.applications, because it was referencing the same object as applications variable, right?

Comment: Indeed. You created a new local variable, that was unrelated to the one in `$scope` :). It had its contents, and if you modified `applications[0]` **directly**, it'd have made a difference (like unshift did), because again, contents is not copied

Comment: Ok, huge thanks for your help. I have forgot that applications is not only an array but an object as well, and being able to modify scope.applications via .sort() function was kinda unexpected for me.